# Making a parallel coordinate plot with ggparcood() (package GGally)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally, parallel-coordinates

I am trying to make a parallel coordinate plot with mean values and min and max as surface. I'm using function `ggparcood()` from package GGally.

I have tried to make that plot with this code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(GGally)
data(iris)
data <- iris
grouped_data_mean <- (data %>% dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% dplyr::summarize_all(funs(mean)))
ggparcoord(grouped_data_mean, columns=c(2:4), groupColumn=1)
```

But I get this:

[image]

I want to plot something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. We can't test your code as it is.

Comment: i made my question clearer ..

Comment: You still need to be more specific. Those ribbons (or confidence interval) are defined by what?

Comment: They can be defined by max and min values of each species for each coordinate.